# How can I find the 'depth' of foreign key relationships on tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Given a table with foreign keys, suppose the tables referenced by the foreign keys have foreign keys themselves, etc. I'm interested in figuring out how to to count the number of total foreign key relationships, and, in particular, determine the longest 'path' from the starting table to the table 'furthest away' in terms of foreign keys.

For example, if table BaseTable has 2 foreign keys, one to TableA and the other to TableB, there would be a total of 2 FK relationships and the longest path is shared twice.

If TableA then had a FK reference to TableC, then there would be a total of 3 FK relationships, and the longest path would be 2, from Base to C.

Comment: What if there's a cyclic dependency?

Comment: I was only thinking in terms of non-cyclic structures, but this is a wonderful question to think about. 

For cyclic dependencies, it'd be okay to 'cut out' the smallest number of foreign key relationships that make the structure cyclic while at the same time reducing the longest path by the shortest amount. 

Suppose 3 tables, T1, T2, T3. T1 has a FK that points to T2, T2 has a FK that points to T3, and T3 has a FK that points to T1. 

If you delete the single FK from T3 to T1 OR delete the single FK from T1 to T2 (but not both), the longest path ( = 2) stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a recursive query, linking on primary key to foreign key.  See: [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).

To get the "farthest distance" you could define a running sum column in the UNION query, like so:

```
WITH MyCTE AS (
SELECT Field1, Field2, ..., 0 AS Level
FROM tblRelationships
...
UNION ALL
SELECT Field1, Field2, ..., Level + 1 AS Level
FROM tblRelationships R INNER JOIN
   MyCTE M ON R.PK = M.FK
...
)
```

You could then select from MyCTE having the Level = the max Level for all rows returned by the CTE.  To get a count of foreign key relationships just do a count from MyCTE.

Make sure to filter for tablename = the base table in your anchor definition in both cases.

Comment: That's a pretty elegant suggestion; I'll give it a try. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Run this: `sp_msdependencies` and look at the results where oType = 8.  Doesn't work with Azure SQL mind you, but should work if you're using 2008.

I use this just to figure out order of operations for loading data.